# How to share Url and text in Masseage app using swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, message, imessage

I have to share text and URL to Message App.

```
if (MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()) {
        let controller = MFMessageComposeViewController()

        //controller.subject =  "http://www.appzoy.com"

        //controller.attachments?.append(["url" : URL(string : "http://www.appzoy.com")!])

        //controller.addAttachmentURL(URL(string : "http://www.appzoy.com")!, withAlternateFilename: "")

        controller.body = "Hey I just gave an Awesome Assessment on UAssess App you can also try it. I scored \(String(describing: myScore!)) , Try to beat my score"

        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self
        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    else  {

        Helper.sharedInstance.Print("No Message Composer Present" as AnyObject)
    }.
```

I am trying to pass url also but it's not going to message App
Anyone know how to share URL Link and text in Message App.

Comment: do want to send text and URL as SMS right?

Comment: Yes @ivarun I want to send text and URL as sms.

Answer (score 2):

Try below code:

```
   let controller = MFMessageComposeViewController()

    if (MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()) {

        let urlToShare = "http://www.appzoy.com"

        controller.body = "Hey I just gave an Awesome Assessment on UAssess App you can also try it. I scored , Try to beat my score \(urlToShare)"

        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self
        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

[image]
Hope this will help you :)

Comment: I did this too. Problem is URL Link is not coming.

Comment: @kishor0011please check screenshot

Comment: OK Let me try again.

Comment: @kishor0011 create `MFMessageComposeViewController` object before  `if (MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()) {`

Comment: Yeah I tried  its not working. Means Link is not coming.
I will tap on link nothing is happen.

Comment: @kishor0011 is screenshot is correct i mean is it output that you want?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154852/discussion-between-ivarun-and-kishor0011).